# Querying a child table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a database in a SQL Server 2008 database. My database model forms a diamond pattern with four tables. Those four tables are defined as follows:

```
Table1
- ID
- Name
- AddedBy

Table2
- ID
- Table1ID
- Name
- Type

Table3
- ID
- Table1ID
- Name

Table4
- ID
- Table2ID
- Table3ID
- Age
```

I am currently getting all of the Table1 records for a specific user by using the AddedBy field. This query looks like this:

```
SELECT
  * 
FROM
  [Table1] t1
WHERE
  t1.[AddedBy]=@someuser
```

Now, I need to get the Age value from the first Table4 record that is somehow associated with Table1. How do I do this? I keep getting confused with the query.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: How are you defining "first"?

Comment: what is the relationship between Table1 and Table4? 1:1, 1:Many?

Comment: Voting to close as too localized.  This is extremely basic SQL and it's unlikely anyone in the future will hit this question in a search about `JOIN`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a classic illustration of how compound primary keys can allow you to more accurately express what you want your database to do.

Given the model that you have, it appears that `Table2` and `Table3` are directly defined by `Table1`; that is, it doesn't make sense to have a `Table2` record without a parent `Table1` record. Likewise, it looks like `Table4` only makes sense when *both* `Table2` and `Table3` exist. If this is true, then `Table2`, `Table3`, and `Table4` should have compound primary keys along these lines:

```
Table2
-------------
Table1ID     -- consider renaming this in Table1 so that the same name is used 
                throughout
RecordNumber -- unique within a given Table1ID; this is only needed if one of 
                your other two columns cannot serve as a unique value within 
                Table1ID, which I'm guessing one of them can
```

Then you'd do something similar for `Table3`. Then, for `Table4`, you'd have:

```
Table4
-------------
Table1ID
Table2RecordNumber
Table3RecordNumber
```

As the primary key, then set up two foreign keys, one to `Table2` on (`Table1ID, Table2RecordNumber`) and one to `Table3` on (`Table1ID, Table3RecordNumber`). This allows you to ensure that your `Table4` records always link to `Table2` and `Table3` records with the same `Table1ID`, and it simplifies the join in the original query so that it doesn't have to go through `Table2` or `Table3` to find a valid record in `Table4`.

Comment: Yes to the idea of redesiging. This will be hard to query without doing so. And yes, yes, yes to getting rid of ID as a name for the ID fields. This is a SQL antipattern and I cringe every time I see it.

Answer (score 2):

> SQL JOIN

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp